# How do I build RAM/CPU with logic circuits?

Tags: cpu, ram, logic-gates

I want to build a little 4 bit computer, out of logic circuits. I want RAM and a CPU and all that good stuff. My main problem is, should I work on RAM or CPU, which one would "teach" me more so that I could build the other, and could someone give me a circuit map? Thanks, if you helped!

Since I have asked this question, I have learned much more about electronics. So on October 1st 2015 I will do a live stream where I will be designing a 4-16 bit computer with logic gates, transistors and nothing else really!
Go [here](http://www.twitch.tv/ender_scythe/profile) to watch.

Comment: Go [here](http://www.nand2tetris.org/) and start learning. The linked Coursera course accompanied with this site is one of the best (actually - the best one) I've seen on the subject.

Comment: RAM will show you the basics. Do that before trying a CPU...

Comment: @Brian Drummond Could you give me a logical gate map?

Comment: Logical gate...what?

Comment: Logic gate map.

Comment: What is this exactly? And why do you think @BrianDrummond has it?

Comment: Logic gates mapped onto paper, with their wire connections. That's what a logic gate map is.

Comment: Do you mean symbols for logical gates? Or their internal implementation? Both can be found easily using a search engine.

Comment: Their symbols, that are then connected in the correct fashion, then after you have connected the gates you run power through the proper circuits and after the circuit has gone through all of the gates, the "computer" gives you a result "1's and 0's" that then can be interpreted.

Comment: So you want someone to design the circuit for you and give you a schematic.  I don't think that's going to happen here.

Comment: A basic schematic...

Comment: A computer (even the simple one) is not a "basic schematic".

Comment: Simulate your proposed design before you build anything more complicated than an adder, address decoder, or example state machine.

Comment: @EnderScythe Know that your project is cool and there's nothing wrong with trying to find a schematic to base your design on. But this question isn't a good fit for this site. It's too broad, and our goal here is to answer specific questions, not design entire circuits for anyone.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can build a computer from scratch.  4-bits is a good choice, since it uses considerably less hardware (but obviously more than half) of an 8-bit computer.  The first commercially available microprocessor, the [4004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004), was a 4-bit device.  Its successor was the [4040](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4040), also a 4-bit device.

In the home-brew computer field, 4 and 8-bits are the norm.  16-bit computers are less common, and I have never seen a 32-bit home-built computer.  (Note -- I am limiting this discussion to designs where the entire computer is built from scratch, i.e. they don't use a conventional microprocessor chip; however some homebrew designs do use the [74181 4-bit ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/74181), commonly found in minicomputers such as the PDP-11).

Here are five 4-bit computers that others have built.  In three of the examples, complete schematics are available.

[Fourbit, 4-bit homebrew CPU](http://jaromir.xf.cz/fourbit/fourbit.html) design, and schematic available

[image]

[4 bit computer built from discrete transistors](https://hackaday.io/project/665-4-bit-computer-built-from-discrete-transistors)  design available

[image]

[Build this 4 bit CPU from TTL ICs.](http://www.galacticelectronics.com/Simple4BitCPU.HTML)   design and schematic available

[image]

[APOLLO181 Homemade 4-bit TTL Processor](http://ygg-it.tripod.com/id6.html)   design and schematic available, uses 74181 ALU

[image]

[Homebrew 4-bit Computer using TTL ICs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aERZuW9KhM)  Youtube video only

One of first things you will need to do is figure out the instruction set.  This is the fun part, as far as I'm concerned, as you visualize how your computer will run your programs.  With just a 4-bit memory path, you will certainly need some instructions longer than 4 bits.  So do you make all instructions double-wide?  Or use variable length instructions?  You choice.

Check out the instruction sets for the computers listed above, in addition to the 4004 and 4040, for ideas.

There are a lot of examples in the [Homebuilt CPUs WebRing](http://members.iinet.net.au/~daveb/simplex/ringhome.html), which include some more 4-bit as well as 8-bit and 16-bit home-built computers.  There's even a couple of relay computers.

Comment: It's pretty cool to see these, I can't imagine the perseverance and ambition of people back in the day to just go and make these things happen. I take so much for granted these days, it's sad. Saw the movie "Jobs" recently, and that was basically it!!